# $L_\kappa$ is model of $ZFC+V=L$ when $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm havig twouble proving this :( any hint?

I've been trying to proof that $V_\kappa=L_\kappa$ when $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, if this is true then i'm done proving that $L_\kappa$ is model of $ZFC$, but i alo don´t know how to proceed :(

Comment: It is not generally true that $V_\kappa=L_\kappa$ for $\kappa$ inaccessible (unless you're assuming $V=L$). Try to argue axiom-by-axiom.

Answer (score 1):

As Noah says in the comments, it's not necessarily true that $V_\kappa=L_\kappa.$ However, if you still want to leverage the fact that $V_\kappa\models \sf ZFC,$ you can show

1. $\kappa$ is inaccessible in $L$
2. $V_\kappa=L_\kappa$ holds in $L$

and then it follows that $L_\kappa \models \sf ZFC$ in $L$, but this is absolute, so $L_\kappa\models \sf ZFC.$

Showing $\kappa$ is inaccessible in $L$ is relatively routine. For the second part, working in $L$, if $x\in V_\kappa,$ then since $\kappa$ is inaccessible, $|\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}|< \kappa.$ Then, it follows from the condensation lemma that $x\in L_\kappa.$

In more detail: Choose a limit ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}\in L_\gamma$ and then let $M\preceq L_\gamma$ with $|M|= |\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}|$ and $\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}\subseteq M.$ By the condensation lemma, the Mostowski collapse of $M$ is $L_\beta$ for some $\beta < |\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}|^+<\kappa.$ Since $\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}$ is transitive, $\operatorname{trcl}\{x\}\subseteq L_\beta,$ so $x\in L_\beta\subseteq L_\kappa.$

Finally, the fact that $L_\kappa\models \sf V=L$ follows from the absoluteness of the relation $x\in L_\beta.$